# White foil ? (toner reactive)

Tags: laser

I'm looking to print something with my laser printer and then foil it, I found silver and gold foil in markets, it worked great, but I'm looking for a white foil. I seen on the internet that there's white foil by deco foil, but unfortunately shopping online is forbidden in my country.. is there anyway I can stick something white to toner ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is about buying either online or elsewhere.